# Adding auto-QC to Snakemake pipeline to filter out samples with bad quality in the middle of the pipeline steps

Tags: python, automation, filtering, pipeline, snakemake

My question is similar to this one: [Conditional execution of multiplexed analysis with snakemake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024818/conditional-execution-of-multiplexed-analysis-with-snakemake)

I tried the dariober's gist answer with "if-else" in shell, but the else sentence output empty file or folder would always been deleted by snakemake and snakemake would report error (I even added "|| true" for each shell command to prevent non-zero exit code but still doesn't help). If I run the if-else shell outside of snakemake, files and folders would be generated though.

I then tried to write python script instead of shell in "run" section, something like:

```
rule G_move_7:
    input: 
        passORnot_file = '{sample}/XXX_RData/{sample}.passORnot.txt',
        sample_folder = '{sample}',
        filtered_bam = '{sample}.Aligned.out.filtered.bam',
    output: 
        move_log = '{sample}.log',
    output
    run:
        with checkpoints.F_XXX_withCheck_6.get(sample=wildcards.sample).output[2].open() as f:
            if f.read().strip() == "PASS":
                os.system("mv -f" + input.filtered_bam + " ./PASS/ > " + output.move_log)
                os.system("mv -f" + input.sample_folder + " ./PASS/ >> " + output.move_log)
                os.system("echo " + input.sample_folder + " ./PASS/ >> " + output.move_log)
            else:
                os.system("mv -f" + input.filtered_bam + " ./NOT_PASS/ > " + output.move_log)
                os.system("mv -f" + input.sample_folder + " ./NOT_PASS/ >> " + output.move_log)
                os.system("echo " + input.sample_folder + " ./NOT_PASS/ >> " + output.move_log)
```

This works but after getting all the passed sample to the folder "PASS", I have to run the downstream steps with a new snakemake file to use wildcards for each samples in the PASS folder. So now my pipeline was cut to two parts. I have to run first piece and then the second snakemake file. This is fine with only one "pass or not" conditions, but if we add more quality check steps, this would become endless and not doable.

Just wonder is there any more efficient and elegant way to do such auto-QC and filtering-out bad samples in snakemake? (or any other alternatives?) It's better that it can write all QC and filtering within one
pipeline files. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let me repeat my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63848059/7070491

The canonical solution to problems like this is to use checkpoints. Consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_results(wildcards):
    qc = pd.read_csv(checkpoints.qc.get().output[0].open(), sep="\t")
    return expand(
        "results/processed/{sample}.txt", 
        sample=qc[qc["some-qc-criterion"] > config["qc-threshold"]]["sample"]
    )


rule all:
    input:
        get_results


checkpoint qc:
    input:
        expand("results/preprocessed/{sample}.txt", sample=config["samples"])
    output:
        "results/qc.tsv"
    shell:
        "perfom-qc {input} > {output}"


rule process:
    input:
        "results/preprocessed/{sample}.txt"
    output:
        "results/processed/{sample.txt}"
    shell:
        "process {input} > {output}"
```

The idea is the following: at some point in your pipeline, after some (let's say) preprocessing, you add a checkpoint rule, which aggregates over all samples and generates some kind of QC table. Then, downstream of that, there is a rule that aggregates over samples (e.g. the rule `all`, or some other aggregation inside of the workflow). Let's say in that aggregation you only want to consider samples that pass the QC. For that, you let the required files (`"results/processed/{sample}.txt"`) be determined via an input function, which reads the QC table generated by the checkpoint rule. Snakemake's checkpoint mechanism ensures that this input function is evaluated **after** the checkpoint has been executed, so that you can actually read the table results and base your decision about the samples on the qc criteria contained in that table. Any intermediate rules (like here the `process` rule) will then be automatically applied by Snakemake when re-evaluating the DAG.

Comment: Thanks. btw, Example line 4 shall be: 

qc = pd.read_csv(checkpoints.qc.get().output[0], sep="\t")  instead of  qc = pd.read_csv(checkpoints.qc.get().output[0].open(), sep="\t")